# Numpy array condition to check if there is element with value +1 of current value

Tags: python, loops, numpy, vectorization

I would like to build something like this if statements into a numpy condition (for argwhere or similar).

```
for i, element in enumerate(array):
    if array[i]+1 == array[i+1]:
        return True
```

Is this possible or is looping through the array the only way?

Comment: See speed considerations below in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.equal()` function as well.

```
import numpy as np

a = [1,2,4,8,12,13]
x = np.array(a)
res = np.equal((x+1)[:-1], x[1:])

print(res)
```

**Out:**

```
[ True False False False  True]
```

**Note:**

If you need speed, as it is usual the case, when we use numpy, it is worth to mention, that this methode is faster then `np.roll()`, what FBruzzesi proposed below and which is an elegant solution as well anyway:

```
import timeit

code1 = """
import numpy as np
a = [1,2,4,8,12,13]
x = np.array(a)
np.equal((x+1)[:-1], x[1:])
"""
elapsed_time1 = timeit.timeit(code1, number=10000)/100
print(elapsed_time1)

code2 = """
import numpy as np
a = [1,2,4,8,12,13]
x = np.array(a)
x+1 == np.roll(x, shift=-1)
"""

elapsed_time2 = timeit.timeit(code2, number=10000)/100
print(elapsed_time2)
```

**Out:**

```
0.00044608700000026147
0.0022752689999970244
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `np.roll` function that shifts the array

```
import numpy as np
array+1 == np.roll(array, shift=-1)
```

This will return an array of boolean values.

Comment: You meant `shift = -1`

Comment: np.roll([1,2,3,4,], shift=1) is array([4, 1, 2, 3]). So you should know that last element compares with first.

Comment: thank you very much I think that is exactly the right answer

Comment: @Aryerez See speed considerations below in my answer

Comment: @Geeocode I have change my answer since like you say it is a faster method and you included a comparison. But I ask that you include a reference to FBruzzesi since you are comparing to his answer.

Comment: @JorgeDiaz Thank you and I made the reference as you required.